# MYSQL: Insert autoincrement value into several columns

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

Can you insert an autoincrement value into several columns at once?

Example table `zoo`:

id (int autoincrement primary_key);

parent (int);

data (varchar,10).

`INSERT INTO zoo (id, parent, data) VALUES (NULL, id, "tiger");`

Or do I have to do a second query?

`UPDATE TABLE zoo SET parent=id WHERE parent IS NULL;`

Comment: There's probably no good reason why you'd want to do this

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this via a before insert trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER same_id_trigger
BEFORE INSERT 
    ON zoo FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE id int DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT auto_increment INTO id
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'zoo' AND table_schema = database();

    SET NEW.parent = id;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Assuming the above trigger works, then it is working by directly querying information schema to find the current auto increment value for the `zoo` table.  Then, the trigger effectively intercepts the insert, and swaps in that auto increment value for the `parent` column.

Comment: Thanks! I did think of triggers but they often confuse me, haha. 
I guess I could also do an AFTER INSERT one and just copy the value across.

Comment: I totally will, but I'm still at the planning stage so It'll be a little while.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea